# How can I set the x axis to a certain hour with scale_x_time, until the same hour the following day?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, scale, axis

I'm trying to visualize time series data from measurements with animals, in ggplot2.

In y-axis I have groups of days for different sets of data, in x-axis I have day time (in hour:min:sec format), and set the color to factors associated to whether the determinations were registered in daylight or in darkness.

My problem is that I need to set the measurement starting point at 7:45am every day and ending point at 7:45am of the following day.

I succeeded to group the data into days by for loops like this one (repeated until during the time we did the experiment):

```
df$Day <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if((ymd_hms(df$Take[i]) - ymd_hms(df$Take[1]) < as_hms(86400))) {
    df$Day[i] <- 1
  } else df$Day[i] <- df$Day[i]
}
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if((ymd_hms(df$Take[i]) - ymd_hms(df$Take[1]) < as_hms(86400*2)) & (ymd_hms(df$Take[i]) - ymd_hms(df$Take[1]) > as_hms(86400))) {
    df$Day[i] <- 2
  } else df$Day[i] <- df$Day[i]
}
```

And I also managed to assign the daylight and darkness categories with this dplyr code:

```
light_a <- as.hms('07:45:00')
light_b <- as.hms('19:45:00')
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Light_dark = if_else(df$Take_Time > light_a &  df$Take_Time < light_b, 'Light', 'Dark'))%>%
  mutate(Light_dark2 = if_else(df$Take_Time > light_a &  df$Take_Time < light_b, '1', '0'))
```

I also defined categories and group the data by days:

```
df2$Day <- as.factor(df2$Day)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(Day, Light_dark)
```

However, I cannot obtain the plot starting by the starting point. What I obtain is a graph with disordered data:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Take_Time,y= as.factor(Day))) +
  geom_point(aes(col = as.factor(Light_dark)),alpha= 0.6, size = 2)+
  labs(subtitle="Feeding system.",y="Day",x="Time (h:m:s)",title="Distribution of the data", color = "Lightness intervals")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('aquamarine3', 'chocolate')) +  
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))
```

I tried to add this `scale_x_time()`, but then the points disappear:

```
scale_x_time(
    labels = "%H:%M", 
    breaks = "2 hours", 
    limits = c(as.hms('07:45:00'),
               as.hms('07:44:00')),
    timezone = Sys.timezone(),
    expand = c(0,0)
  ) +
```

Any idea to fix the plot is welcomed.

Comment: Please can you share enough data to make your problem reproducible. Please use `dput(df)` to make the data into an easily imported format

Comment: Thank you. I finally splitted the ggplot graph into two plots: one with the x-axis from 7:45am to midnight, and the other one from midnight to the 7:45am of the following day.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to inform I managed to get a proper plot by calculating differences.

If the difference of the value and midnight is lower than the difference of my cutoff value and midnight, means it is in the time range between the starting point and midnight and I leave the value as it is.

If the difference is bigger, means that it is actually the range of time between midnight and the cutoff of the following day, and what I do is to sum the value to midnight's one.
Afterwards, I change the labels in the ggplot2 command.

```
df2$crono <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  if((as_hms('24:00:00') - as_hms(df2$Take_Time[i])) <= (as_hms('24:00:00') -
                                                            as_hms('07:45:00'))) {
    df2$crono[i] <- ((as_hms(df2$Take_Time[i])))
  } else df2$crono[i] <- ((as_hms('24:00:00') + as_hms(df2$Take_Time[i])))
}

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = crono,y= as.factor(Day))) +
  geom_point(aes(col = as.factor(Light_dark)),alpha= 0.6, size = 2)+
  labs(subtitle="Feeding system.",y="Day",x="Time (h:m:s)",title="Distribution of the data", 
       color = "Lightness intervals")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('aquamarine3', 'chocolate')) +  
  scale_x_continuous( limits = c( 25000, 115000),
                      breaks= c(28800,43200,57600,72000,86400,100800,115200),
                      labels=c("08:00","12:00","16:00","20:00","24:00","04:00","08:00"))+ 
theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))
```

[Plot of the distribution data with fixed x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn290.png)